# Can Chrome App Retrieve or Inject data to Web Pages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, code-injection

I want to develop an app (for Chrome desktop) that will retrieve data from different webpages the user surf to and aggregate it, or inject some added JavaScript functionality to those pages, later on showing the user statistics about the webpages he surf to. Like how many pages the user have been having more that 3 images in them.

Now, I know Chrome Extensions can Inject JavaScript code and therefor also retrieve data, but I want my App to be a Chrome App. Can it also pull data from WebPages and / or Inject JS to those pages ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Chrome App is, by design, isolated from the browser. You can't enumerate tabs, inject content scripts, etc. at all, as you can see from an entirely different list of [available APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index).

While you could [embed a pseudo-browser](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser) in your app using the [`<webview>` tag](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), it's going to be hard to convince the user to use your limited browser over "real" Chrome.

If you want to interact with a browser, you need an extension. If you *also* really need Chrome App capabilities you'll need both separately, and they can [talk to each other](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external).

Comment: Thanks. I will have to go on the both app and extension scenario and they will talk with each other. *Sigh*.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Consider [Native Hosts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) as well as an alternative.